# force file download handling

Tags: php, http-headers, sleep

I am trying to understand how the response is created for force downloads and how the browser handles it.

Following this article here: [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039).

I have a script that sends a file as response to download.

```
<?php
// it's a zip file
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
// 1 million bytes (about 1megabyte)
header('Content-Length: 1000000');
// load a download dialogue, and save it as download.zip
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.zip"');

// 1000 times 1000 bytes of data
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    echo str_repeat(".",1000);

    // sleep to slow down the download
    // sleep(5);
}
sleep(5);
```

When the `sleep()` function is inside the loop, it waits for sometime before the file starts downloading.

But when placed outside the loop, file starts downloading immediately.

Can anyone please help me understand this behaviour?

Comment: inside its hanging for each iteration, outside its waiting. both are useless and wouldn't use in real code

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes.. this is just a dummy script.. as mentioned in the article also.

Comment: What'd you happen if you write this `$a=1` after sleep (in 2nd case). My guess is php sees there is not remaining output anymore to buffer and it flushes immediately..but I'm not sure

Comment: @Viney file gets downloaded immediately. could it be the issue with output buffers?

Comment: Your sleep is not going to do what you think it might do. Why are you trying to "slow the download" as you put it?

Comment: @Dave that is just a dummy script, maybe simulating the server file generation delay?

Comment: Any delay in generating a file will happen well before you start downloading. And there is buffering going on between your script and the end user that you can't control. If you want to simulate a delay it should be before that first header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the second case is you send the file to the client before you call the sleep function.
You can store the output in an internal buffer and send it after the sleep function. (I don't recommend this for production use.)
Try this modified program:

```php
<?php
// it's a zip file
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
// 1 million bytes (about 1megabyte)
header('Content-Length: 1000000');
// load a download dialogue, and save it as download.zip
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.zip"');

//Turn on output buffering
ob_start();

// 1000 times 1000 bytes of data
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    echo str_repeat(".",1000);

    // sleep to slow down the download
    // sleep(5);
}

//Store the contents of the output buffer
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
// Clean the output buffer and turn off output buffering
ob_end_clean();

sleep(5);

echo $buffer;
```

Comment: @Andrais.. so the first `echo` in the first `iteration` immediately starts outputting to the browser and ignores the further iterations??

Comment: I talked about the second case where the sleep function placed outside the for loop and the entire file is sent before the sleep function, but yes it will start outputting unless you use output buffering. You can try it in a terminal.